# Django admin, many-to-many, saving to and retrieving from DB

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a rather simple relationship between two models: a `Person` and cities that the person has visited (`City`).

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```

I am writing an admin page for this, and I have a separate form class for `Person` which doesn't mention cities at all, and I have a class inheriting from `admin.ModelAdmin`, which does.

I need to call a function, passing the completely saved instance of `Person`, with all of the fields properly updated and saved to the db, including the cities. However, whichever of the `save...` methods I override, I can get the `Person` instance to get saved and can read the new values from the db, however, I can't get the updated cities from the db. The ones that I have tried are `save_m2m` and `_save_m2m` in the form, `save_form`, `save_related` in the ModelAdmin. In each of these locations I call `super().<the method>` and then check `person.cities.all()`. Each time I get the old value (the one that was in the db before the update, and not the new value from the form).

Is there a location I can tap into to get the actual saved and commited value of the many-to-many field? Is there a way to wrap anything in `transaction.atomic` or anything of that sort? Or am I doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So far what I ended up doing is overriding the `changeform_view` method:

```
def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    result = super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bundle = Person.objects.prefetch_related('cities').get(pk=object_id)
        notify_search(bundle)

    return result
```

Not sure if it is the best solution. I'll be happy to accept anybody else's solution if it is better.